# Simulating curl in python

Tags: python, curl

I am trying to simulate this curl command in python:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "auth_token": "auth", "widget": "widgetid", "title": "Something", "text": "Some text", "moreinfo": "Subtitle" }' http://domain.com
```

Until now I have tried to send it with python requests but every time the order changes.

Is there any way to simulate this in python?

UPDATE:

To see what is different I have started a nc server locally. Here are the results:

Correct curl request using this code:

```
 curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "auth_token": "auth", "widget": "widgetid", "title": "Something", "text": "Some text", "moreinfo": "Subtitle" }' http://localhost:8123
```

sends this **which does work:**

```
 POST / HTTP/1.1
 User-Agent: curl/7.21.0 (i386-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.0 NSS/3.12.10.0 zlib/1.2.5  libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.2.4
 Host: localhst:8123
 Accept: */*
 Content-Type: application/json
 Content-Length: 165

 { "auth_token": "auth", "widget": "widgetid", "title": "Something", "text": "Some text", "moreinfo": "Subtitle" }
```

And request using this code

```
  import requests
  import simplejson as json

  url = "http://localhost:8123"
  data = {'auth_token': 'auth', 'widget': 'id1', 'title': 'Something1', 'text': 'Some   text', 'moreinfo': 'Subtitle'}
  headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
  r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

sends this which **does not work:**

```
 POST / HTTP/1.1
 Host: localhst:8123
 Content-Length: 108
 Content-type: application/json
 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress
 Accept: */*
 User-Agent: python-requests/2.0.1 CPython/2.7.0 Linux/2.6.35.14-106.fc14.i686

 {"text": "Some text", "auth_token": "auth", "moreinfo": "Subtitle", "widget": "id1",  "title": "Something1"}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the order changes"? How does your Python code look like? (Congratulations to choose Requests over urllib2, by the way.)

Comment: If you mean that the order of the post-ed json dictionary changes - this is because the order of keys is completely irrelevant to the json dictionary specification. Unless something is very broken, the client won't care about the order of keys either.

Comment: Here I am updating it..

Comment: Does the server expect a User-Agent? Is your auth_token supposed to be different?

Comment: Sorry auth token is the same. Im updating it.

Comment: What do you mean by "**does not work**" ? It looks to me like it worked perfectly. What error message appears, or what doesn't work? Your attention to ordering may be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: The content-length field of the first example seems off. Is the example a literal copy-paste, or did you tweak it?

Comment: I am executing the same command using curl and using requests. @Robᵩ  does not work means in the server it is not accepted.

Comment: What server is being used? What is the error message that it returns? Can you examine the server logs to get more information?

Comment: @Robᵩ I am only able to see a 401 in the server side. It is a ruby aplication running on heroku that accepts those valors.

Comment: That indicates that the client has either not provided an "Authorization:" header, or that the authorization value is invalid. Please 1) run curl with a "-D" or "-i" switch, and 2) in your Python code, print the value of `r.status_code` and `r.headers`. Paste the results in your question. See also http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt